# How to pass a DateTime into a Stored Procedure using Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I have this Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsDateInBetween]
    @someDateTime datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Exists INT

    IF EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] 
               WHERE StartDate < @someDateTime AND EndDate > @someDateTime)
    BEGIN
        SET @Exists = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Exists = 0
    END

    RETURN @Exists
END
```

When I call it:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[IsDateInBetween]
        @someDateTime = N'2020-07-14'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I receive 1, which is expected.

But then I try to call it in C#:

```
var result = DbConnection.ExecuteScalar<int>("dbo.IsDateInBetween", new { new DateTime(2020, 7, 14) }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

And I get 0.

I tried to change the passed object to DynamicParameters, like that:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("someDateTime", faultDateTime, DbType.DateTime);
```

But it didn't help.

I tried both DbType.DateTime and DbType.DateTime2, as well as parameter name starting with @ and without it.
Both columns from the stored procedure are of type datetime.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, when I pressed F12 I was moved to SqlMapper class in the Dapper namespace, assembly version 1.16.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give your parameter the correct name:

```cs
var result = DbConnection.ExecuteScalar<int>(
    "IsDateInBetween", 
    new { someDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 7, 14) }, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Also, Unless you're executing a schema that is different than the login's default schema, you don't need to mention it, the procedure name is enough.

And another thing - the problem is probably in the stored procedure itself. You're not suppose to use `Return` - you're suppose to either use an output parameter or a simple select.

Try this procedure instead:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsDateInBetween]
    @someDateTime datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT Id 
        FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] 
        WHERE StartDate < @someDateTime 
        AND EndDate > @someDateTime
    )
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
END
```

Comment: At first, I tried with the parameter name, but it didn't work. Then I changed the stored procedure the way you suggested and it actually did the trick! I need to learn more about return values because coming from C# this is not intuitive for me to have a return value 0, and a "no column name" with the correct value :-)

Comment: Don't think of SQL in terms of a programming language - it is not. It's a different paradigm that takes time to learn and adjust your thought process to, if you're coming from a programming background.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Query` or `QueryAsync` Or any of the other query methods like `QueryFirst` or `QueryFirstOrDefault`.
`ExecuteScalar` is an [ADO.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method and also exists in dapper so it might not be clear witch one you are using.

For dapper try

```
DbConnection.QueryFirst<int>("EXEC dbo.IsDateInBetween @someDate", new { someDate = new DateTime(2020, 7, 14) });
```

Why use `Query()` instead of `Execute()`? You expect a return value.

Also you should specify the name of the parameter in your query and in your anonymous type.